# Атомарное удаление файлов в Python

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система

Есть список с путями до файлов, эти файлы удаляются в цикле, внутри цикла ещё некоторые операции выполняются, но проблема в том что обязательно нужно сохранить атомарность операции.

Т.е. если внутри цикла что-то обвалится, другие, ранее удалённые файлы, через системный api `os.remove(path)`, естественно удаляются.
Собственно вопрос, есть ли какие-то пакеты, для выполнения "транзакции" удаления файлов, и последующим коммитом.

Типа, некой корзины и последующей её очисткой.

Comment: Непонятно. О каком коммите речь?

Comment: Предлагаю сделать как раз "корзину". В цикле вы файлы перемещаете в какую-то папку, после цикла из папки удаляете файлы. Если же при перемещении в папку произошла ошибка, то все файлы из папки обратно перемещаются в исходную. Перемещение имеет с удалением похожие черты :)

Comment: не ясно: вы хотите удалить либо все файлы либо ни одного в зависимости от успеха неких третих операций? Или каждая итерация это своя транзакция у вас?

Answer (score 1):

особо не проверял правильность работы, но както так

```
import os, shutil, uuid, time

def at_delete(files_list: [str, ], move_files=None):
    files_list = set(files_list)
    if not tmp_dir:
        tmp_dir = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Типа, некой корзины и последующей её очисткой.
        os.makedirs(tmp_dir, exist_ok=True)
    move_files = dict(bad=set(), good=dict(),)  # атомарность операции

    def move(files: set):
        """для выполнения "транзакции" удаления файлов"""
        func = lambda: None
        files = files.copy()
        move_files['bad'] = set()
        for file in files:  # эти файлы удаляются в цикле
            try:
                func()  # внутри цикла ещё некоторые операции выполняются
                new_file = os.path.join(tmp_dir, file)
                shutil.move(file, new_file)  # "удаляются" - переместить файлы
                move_files['good'][file] = new_file
            except Exception as ex:  # Т.е. если внутри цикла что-то обвалится
                move_files['bad'].add(file)

    move(files_list)
    yield move_files['bad']  # можно удалить или нет
    commit = yield  # сопрограмма коммит
    if commit:
        while move_files['bad']:  # и последующим коммитом
            move(move_files['bad'])
            yield move_files['bad']
            commit = yield
            if not commit:
                break
    if not commit:  # вернуть все файлы из корзины
        for (old_file, new_file) in move_files['good'].items():
            shutil.move(new_file, old_file)
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir, ignore_errors=True)  # "очистить корзину"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files_list = ['geckodriver.log', ]  # список с путями до файлов
    ob = at_delete(files_list)
    fail_move_files = next(ob)
    while fail_move_files:  # пока есть неудаляемые файлы
        ob.send('commit')  # пытатся удалить
        fail_move_files = next(ob)
        next(ob)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: «особо не проверять» удаление файлов немножко небезопасно, [можно случайно всю систему удалить](https://habr.com/post/204580/)...))